# How to reference a component's props interface in Vue3?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm trying to reference a component's props type. Here's where I'm stuck.

**Single file component (*.vue)**

```
<template>
  <calendar v-bind="propsComputed"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Calendar from './Calendar.vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    ...
    computed: {
      propsComputed () { // TSC ERROR HERE
         return {
           someProp: ...,
           someProp2: ...
         }
      }
    }
    ...
  })
</script>
```

**The `tsc` error:**

`"propsComputed" implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type`

One solution would be to export a type in `Component.vue` using `export type {...}` and then import it in the parent. Is there another way? Something like `typeof Component.props`?

Comment: you should have `computed:{` instead `computed () {`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, yep, thanks! But the problem is still there.

Comment: How do you define the props?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-return-types